# Finite and non-finite clauses: "We have washed the dishes"

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, nonfinite-verbs, finite-verbs

I have a quick question regarding finite and non-finite clauses if I may?

In clauses that contain modal or auxiliary verbs marked for tense AND a non-finite element, is the clause finite or non-finite?

For example, are:

> We had washed the dishes

... and

> I have been thinking

... finite because of the tense dictated by *had* and  *have*, or are they non-finite because of the participles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call *to-infinitive* **infinitive** because it is not finite (infinite). To-infinitive and present participle can't indicate any tense because they can't inflect (change their forms).

Finite clauses should contain a verb which shows tense.

> We **had washed** the dishes. I **have been thinking**

Both clauses are finite because the words in bold are indicating tenses and aspects.